# Bounding the Jacobian determinant for "sublipschitz" function

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I'm practicing for my upcoming exam in calculus 3. I came across the following question in a practice paper:

> $ f:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3 $, f is $C^1$. Also, $K|p-p'| \le |f(p)-f(p')|$ for all $p, p' \in \mathbb R^3$ (where $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm and $K>0$ is a real constant). Prove that $K^3 v(\Omega) \le v(f(\Omega))$ for every Jordan measurable $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^3$ ($v$ is the Jordan measure on $\mathbb R^3$)

I approached the question as follows. First, I noticed I can prove $f$ is a diffeomorphism $\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow f(\mathbb R^3)$ such that $D_f (x)$ is an invertible matrix for every $x\in\mathbb R^3$. Provided this is true, using variable substitution theorem, I can obtain the equality $v(f(\Omega))=\int_{f(\Omega))} 1 = \int_{\Omega} |J_f(x)|dx$, where $J_f (x) = det(D_f(x))$ is the Jacobian determinant.

Now, I wanted to prove $(*)$ $|J_f (x)| \ge K^3$. From this I'll get $\int_{\Omega} |J_f(x)|dx \ge K^3 \int_{\Omega} 1 = K^3 v(\Omega)$, thus completing the proof.

However, though $(*)$ seems intuitively true to me, I couldn't manage to prove it. In particular, I tried primarily to rely on the equality $det(D_f(x)) = lim_{Q\downarrow x} \frac{v(f(Q))}{v(Q)}$, where $Q$ is a cube centered around $x$ and $Q\downarrow x$ means $Q$'s area approaches zero. Regardless, nothing I tried worked.

Any help in proving $(*)$ will be much appreciated, particularly if it was done with the equality I mentioned above. Thanks!

Comment: I think that this is going to boil down to some linear algebra problem. It might help to start considering a special case, with $f(x, y, z)=(f_1(x), f_2(y), f_3(z))$. Here $Df(p)$ is a diagonal matrix and it should be easier to prove your conjecture. This first step should provide some insight.

Comment: (BTW: I agree on your strategy and I think that your conjecture that $|Jf(x)|\ge K^3$ is true)

Comment: I couldn't work it out, I'm afraid. I did realize that I might be able to prove my conjecture if I managed to prove that every eigenvalue of the Jacobian matrix is greater or equal to K. Unfortunately, I have no clue how to even attempt that.

Comment: And of course, much obliged, Giuseppe.

Comment: Try this. If $Df(p)$ is upper triangular, then its determinant is  $\partial_x f^1(p)\partial_yf^2(p)\partial_zf^3(p)$. From the condition $|f(p+h)-f(p)|\ge K|h|$, one gets that $|\partial_{x_j}f^j(p)|\ge K$, and so the determinant is bigger than $K^3$.

Comment: Problem is, what if $Df(p)$ is not triangular? Well, then you can apply a Gaussian elimination to that. This amounts to a linear change of variable that makes it triangular. I am sure that this idea is used, for example in the book Real and complex analysis by Rudin, to prove that the Jacobian determinant actually is the volume element.

Comment: It is just a very rough draft, sorry about that. It might or might not lead somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still interested? Here's a working approach (modulo errors of mine):

The assumptions give that 
$$
\epsilon K\lvert \vec h\rvert \le \lvert f(p+\epsilon\vec h)-f(p)\rvert,$$
so letting $\epsilon\to 0$ one gets 
$$
\lvert Df(p)h\rvert\ge K\lvert h\rvert,\qquad \forall h\in \mathbb{R}^n.$$
From now on it is a matter of linear algebra:

**Linear Algebra Problem**.
Suppose that the matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ satisfies the relation 
$$\tag{1}
\lvert Ah\rvert^2\ge K^2 \lvert h\rvert^2,\qquad \forall h\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$
Then $\lvert \det A\rvert \ge K^n$.

*Sketch of proof*. As you rightly point out the determinant is the product of all (complex) eigenvalues. So one needs to prove:

1. Relation (1) holds for $h\in\mathbb{C}^n$ as well;
2. Relation (1) implies that $\lvert \lambda\rvert\ge K$ for any eigenvalue $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ of $A$.

$\square$

Hope this helps